# How can I copy the results of the JavaScript button action onto another html page?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My code works fine but I don't know what to add to it to append it to another html page instead of to the same document's body. Yes, same website, domain name etc, I have not created the page yet. No frames. The aim is to print the text created:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<body>
        
<p>Click the button to create a P element with some text, and append it to the document's body.</p>            
<button onclick="myFunction()">Blanc</button>    
    
<script>    
function myFunction() {    
    var x = document.createElement("P");    
    var t = document.createTextNode("Blanc.");    
    x.appendChild(t);    
    document.body.appendChild(x);    
}    
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Fauve à panachures blanches</button>
        
<script>

function myFunction2() {    
    var x = document.createElement("P");    
    var t = document.createTextNode("Fauve à panachures blanches");    
    x.appendChild(t);    
    document.body.appendChild(x);    
}

</script>
        
<button onclick="myFunction3()">Bonnes allures typiques</button>
        
<script>

function myFunction3() {    
    var x = document.createElement("P");    
    var t = document.createTextNode("Bonnes allures typiques");    
    x.appendChild(t);    
    document.body.appendChild(x);    
}

</script>
    
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry Bernie, it's unclear what you are asking for? Does your code not work? Are you getting any errors? What errors are you getting? Give us something.

Comment: Yes, my code works fine but I don't know what to add to it to append it to  another html page instead of to the same document's body.

Comment: Is this other HTML page in an iframe? Also, is it from the same origin? Are both pages coming from the same website and domain name?

Comment: Yes, same website, domain name etc, I have not created the page yet. No frames. The aim is to print the text created.

Answer (score 0):

If I understanding correctly, you just want to use the same javascript code on another HTML document, but without copy/pasting the code.  Right?

To do this you just need to save your JS code into a file, let's call it `my-scripts.js`

```js
function myFunction() {    
    var x = document.createElement("P");    
    var t = document.createTextNode("Blanc.");    
    x.appendChild(t);    
    document.body.appendChild(x);    
}   
function myFunction2() {    
    var x = document.createElement("P");    
    var t = document.createTextNode("Fauve à panachures blanches");    
    x.appendChild(t);    
    document.body.appendChild(x);    
}

function myFunction3() {    
    var x = document.createElement("P");    
    var t = document.createTextNode("Bonnes allures typiques");    
    x.appendChild(t);    
    document.body.appendChild(x);    
}
```

Now in your HTML, you can remove those scripts you pasted and just add a single `<scipt>` tag at the bottom that has a path to your new JS file you saved.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<body>
        
  <p>Click the button to create a P element with some text, and append it to the document's body.</p>            
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Blanc</button>    
  <button onclick="myFunction2()">Fauve à panachures blanches</button>      
  <button onclick="myFunction3()">Bonnes allures typiques</button>

  <script src='path/to/my-scripts.js'></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

You can add that script link `<script src='path/to/my-scripts.js'></script>` on any HTML file you want, just make sure the path is correctly pointing to the file relative to where the HTML file is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sessionStorage to create and access variables across different pages. Here, because of sandbox restrictions, I'm using sandboxStorage, but you should use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Since sessionStorage cannot save DOM nodes, you need to serialize to string, and then deserialize when you need an element. [This article](https://grrr.tech/posts/create-dom-node-from-html-string/) describes various methods and their trade-offs.

```js
const sandboxStorage = {
  data: {}
};
sandboxStorage.getItem = (key) => {
  return sandboxStorage.data[key];
};
sandboxStorage.setItem = (key,value) => {
  sandboxStorage.data[key] = value;
};

const saveElement = (key, html) => {
  sandboxStorage.setItem(key, html);
};

const getElement = (key) => {
  const html = sandboxStorage.getItem(key);
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
  return doc.body.firstChild;
};

const appendNode = (node) => {
  document.querySelector('#appendHere').appendChild(node);
};

const func1 = () => {
  const key = 'element1';
  const html = `<p>Blanc.</p>`;
  saveElement(key,html);
  const node = getElement(key);
  appendNode(node);
};

const func2 = () => {
  const key = 'element2';
  const html = `<p>Fauve à panachures blanches</p>`;
  saveElement(key,html);
  const node = getElement(key);
  appendNode(node);
};


const func3 = () => {
  const key = 'element3';
  const html = `<p>Bonnes allures typiques</p>`;
  saveElement(key,html);
  const node = getElement(key);
  appendNode(node);
};
```

```css
p {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: Indigo;
}
```

```html
<html>    
<body>
        
<p>Click the buttons to save elements to sessionStorage for later retreival</p>            

<button onclick="func1()">Blanc</button>
<button onclick="func2()">blanches</button>
<button onclick="func3()">typiques</button>

<div id="appendHere"></div>
```